# Is the use of "as...as..." correct in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read a sentence in an article:

> If these volcanoes were active *as recently as 100 million years ago* (an estimate of the time of last eruption based on the extent of impact cratering on the their slopes), some of them may still be least intermittently active.

I wonder if the "as...as..." part in the sentence is decent english, and is it equal to "if these volcanoes were *as active recently as they were 100 millions years ago*"? I'm curious whether it is fine to change the order of words like the writer does.

Comment: My two cents is, since "recently" is an adverb modifying "active" and "as ... as" is decorating "recently" not "active", "active as recently as" is more natural than "as active recently as". Waiting for a professional response...

Comment: The writer has not "changed" the correct order. The sentence is perfectly normal.

Comment: It’s correct as is. Compare, “I saw George as recently as last month.”

Comment: To answer your second question - the two sentences are not equal. The orriginal version says that the volcanoes **were** active around 100 million years ago and some might still be occasionally active. It implies that the activity is now much less or ceased. Your version is saying they are still as active now as they were 100 million years ago.

Comment: Thanks! @PaulTanenbaum

Comment: Thanks, that's clear!@PeterJennings